# Expressing a 3-cycle in $S_5$ as a product of two $5$-cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In $S_5$ prove that any $3$-cycle is a product of two $5$-cycles. 
My arguments are as follows: There are $24$ five cycles in $S_5$ and they generate $A_5$ since $A_5$ is Simple. All $3$-cycles also generate $A_5$. Hence any $3$-cycle is a product of $5$-cycles. But how do I conclude it is a product of exactly $2$ five cycles. Help please.

Comment: I suspect you are being too abstract.  A three cycle is $(a,b,c)$ for some $a,b,c$, so show that there are two specific five-cycles that multiply together to form it.

Comment: Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to show it for a specific $3$-cycle, as every other can be obtained by just relabeling numbers (i.e. conjugating in $S_5$).

Now take any two $5$-cycles that multiply to a $3$-cycle, e.g. $(12345)(13254)=(142)$. You are done.

Comment: It didn’t strike me that any example would do because it’s only a label. Thank you for this important idea which will help in other problems as well.

Comment: It is a consequence of the peculiar fact that in $S_n$ two elements are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle structure.

Comment: This property is clear to me about conjugates in Sn but I don’t understand how you relate it to this problem. Can you please throw more light on the connection please?

Comment: (a) All $3$-cycles form a single conjugacy class, (b) conjugation preserves the cycle structure. You have that $$(12345)(13254)=(142)$$

Pick another $3$-cycle, e.g. $(123)$. Using (a), there is an element $g \in S_5$ such that $g(142)g^{-1} = (123)$. Now if you conjugate both sides you get
$$g(12345)g^{-1}g(13254)g^{-1}=g(142)g^{-1}$$

On the right you get $(123)$. On the left you get two possibly different elements that, because of (b), are still $5$-cycles. So you found two $5$-cycles whose product is $(123)$.

Comment: Thank you for your meticulous explanation.

Answer (score 0):

(15342) followed by (13524) gives (123).

So by substituting appropriately you can get any 3-cycle.